# dpkg error on fresh install

Tags: noobs, dpkg

i am new to the raspberry and just setup my first one with a fresh NOOBS installation. First thing i did was mounting my external hard drive. Next i did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. And i get an error...

```
dpkg: error processing package dmsetup (--configure):
  too-long line or missing newline in `/var/lib/dkpg/triggers/update-initramfs``
Erors were encountered while processing:
  dmsetup
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your raspberry pi configuration

```
uname -a
```

Follow the below steps

1. copy the status file for future

   `sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-old`
2. empty the status file

   `sudo echo "" >/var/lib/dpkg/status`
3. populate the status file

   `sudo apt-get update`
4. Upgrade using the below command

   `sudo apt-get upgrade`
5. Update the firmware

   `sudo rpi-update`

This usually happens for debian machines. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have Raspian installed which is debian based. However i reinstalled Raspian via Noobs in the meantime and afterwards i had another, yet similar, dpkg error. Something with some mime package. However i tried to use your solution but on `sudo echo "" > /var/lib/dpkg/status` i got permission denied (even with sudo?). I thought the file might be locked and tried reboot... well it didn't boot anymore. So this time a simple `apt-get update / upgrade` broke my whole system? Once again, i have a brand new raspberry pi 2 b+ with Raspian via Noobs i downloaded just some days ago.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that the solution did not do much good for you. If you are going to have fresh installation of Raspbian then I would suggest using the latest one Noobs 1.9.2 - Noobs 1.9.2 - https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS_latest. I recently upgraded my Raspberry Pi from 1.4 version to 1.9.2. It works really good and when I turned off the GUI to console through raspi-config I got some good performance as well. Also the pi store packages are also depreciated on the latest version.

Comment: Well i guess it was not the solution but the error itself that caused the problem. I am on Noobs 1.9.2. Do you have any idea why i might not be able to write thet dpkg status file even as sudo? For me at the moment the problem is that i cannot do `apt-get update/upgrade` because everytime it is failing... and this with my brandnew raspberry pi and fresh raspian installation. Should i do something else before updating/upgrading?

Comment: @patman can you tell me the permissions of this file. Can you check https://thepcspy.com/read/fixing-dpkg-status-corruption/. Also try performing a sudo rpi-update. Some times updating firmware also fixes the issue.

Comment: The permission are -rw-r--r--, belonging to root. I tried over and over and no luck, so i completely emtied the sd card and reinstalled everything from ground. I tried to empty the dpkg status file before apt-get operations bit permission was denied. I could however delete it (strange?) and touch for a new one. But after `apt-get update&&upgrade` it remained empty. I tried to install samba package and again dpkg failed because libc6 and multiarch-support are not configured. :-(